# SonarQube cannot measure unit tests runs with PowerMockito

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, sonarqube, powermockito

When I run unit tests with the coverage, I can see that lines are covered by unit tests. But when I commit them Sonarqube shows that lines are uncovered. How can i configure sonarqube to measure unit test written with using powermockito?

Answer (score 1):

First of all read the docs of [SonarJava](http://preferable%20read%20the%20docs%20-%20https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project) - actually everything you need to know is in there :D

short outline:

1. you need to generate a report for the coverage with eg. JaCoCo or Cobertura
2. you need to provide a property with a path to those reports eg. for JaCoCo `sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=<path>`
3. you run the analysis and sonar will use those reports